# how to check if text file contains string?

Tags: python, text, contains

**Hello, so, i'm having trouble to find if text file contains string.
for example.**
and i want to create program to check if this file contains string 'banana'.
i have tried this but it didn't work

```
with open("test.txt","r") as f:
    content = f.read()
    for line in content:
        if 'banana' in line:
            do_something()
        else:
            exit()
```

text file looks like this:

```
banana is yellow
apple is red
python is good
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need looping 'cause your file is just text, so just use conditional

```
with open("test.txt","r") as f:
    content = f.read()
    if 'banana' in content:
        do_something()
    else:
        exit()
```